# Removing specific values within a XML element using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, remove-if

During my XSL transformation, I would like to delete all the  tags with ContextID="de_DE".  This means that the following XML:

```
 <Values>       
 <Value AttributeID="TEST" ContextID="de_DE" QualifierID="de">1234</Value>        
 <Value AttributeID="TEST" ContextID="fr_FR" QualifierID="fr">1234</Value>        
 <Value AttributeID="TEST100" ContextID="de_DE" QualifierID="de">abcd</Value>        
 <Value AttributeID="TEST100" ContextID="fr_FR" QualifierID="fr">abcd</Value>        
 </Values>
```

Will become:

```
 <Values>         
 <Value AttributeID="TEST" ContextID="fr_FR" QualifierID="fr">1234</Value>
 <Value AttributeID="TEST100" ContextID="fr_FR" QualifierID="fr">abcd</Value>        
 </Values>
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT doesn't have a notion of 'deletion'. You exclude nodes from the input document by matching them and doing nothing with them. XSLT processors do have a notion of specificity, so a more specific template overrides a less-specific one.

Something like:

```
<!-- Matches all Value elements and copies them verbatim -->
<xsl:template match="Value">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Matches all Value elements whose ContextID is 'de_DE' in preference to the less-specific template, and does nothing -->
<xsl:template match="Value[@ContextID='de_DE']"/>
```

Comment: A shallow copy with `xsl:copy` does not copy the elements with its attributes as the poster wants so while the empty template for those elements to be removed is fine the other templates nees to be improved or perhaps simply be substituted by the identity transformation template.

Comment: @MartinHonnen oops, well spotted. Yes, an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` would be preferable assuming the OP already has an identity transfomation set up.